# Return jQuery object from DataTables render function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to return a jQuery object inside of a `render` function. Since that doesn't seem possible, the code below is as close as I got.

Is this an acceptable solution? When is type `type` called? I can't seem to find any info about it in the docs.

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A']
];

$('#example').dataTable( {
    columns: [
        { 
            "title": "Engine", 
            "className": "foo", 
            "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {

                var $td = $('#example').DataTable().cell(meta.row, meta.col).nodes().to$();

                if(type === 'type'){
                    var $a = $('<a href="#"/>').data({ data: row }).text('foo');
                    $td.html($a);
                }


                return data;
          },
        },
        { "title": "Browser" },
        { "title": "Platform" },
        { "title": "Version", "className": "center" },
        { "title": "Grade", "className": "center" }
    ],

    data: dataSet
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y3fnvzad/7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When function is specified for [render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option, DataTables will call [render](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function multiple times for the different data types that it needs - sorting, filtering and display.

Also, per documentation:

> The return value from the function is what will be used for the data
>   requested.

So you need to return a string (not jQuery object) that will contain data for type of operation requested.

If you would like to construct a link using jQuery, you need to return HTML string when `type` equals to `display`, see the code excerpt below:

```
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            if(type === 'display'){
                return $('<a href="#"/>')
                   .text('foo')
                   .wrap('<div></div>')
                   .parent()
                   .html();
            } else {
                return data;
            }
      },
```

**UPDATE:**

It doesn't makes sense to assign data to the element using jQuery `data()` since we're returning HTML string not jQuery object. In the example below I have demonstrated how you can access row data, when link is clicked.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'a', function(){
    // Get row data 
    console.log($('#example').DataTable().row($(this).closest('tr')).data());
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3fnvzad/10/) for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for the input. My idea was to have the row objects associated with each link. I'm afraid your solution won't work as far as the jQuery `data()` / `$.cache` is concerned: http://jsfiddle.net/y3fnvzad/9/

Comment: @Johan, the problem with your JSFiddle is that `data()` doesn't make sense because `render` returns HTML string, not jQuery object. Besides querying right after DataTables initialization is not correct, it needs time to do the rendering. I have updated the answer to demonstrate how you can retrieve the data without storing it in the `a` element.

Comment: The issue is that when I have more than one link, I would like to set a subset of the `data` to each of them. But I managed to solve it based on your help, thanks!

Comment: How/where is type set?

Comment: @chad,  `type` is set by DataTables to indicate type of operations performed, see [this](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#object) for more information.